# Remove functional property in ontology using jena

Tags: jena, ontology

Currently I am using Jena to work around ontology file, but could not find a way to remove functional attribute from certain property.

Could anyone point out how to do this using Jena?

-- Edit --

What I wanted to do is to iterate all over the properties in the ontology and if it found functionalProperty, then convert it into non-functional property

My code is something like this:

```
    Iterator<OntProperty> ont = model.listOntProperties();
    while(ont.hasNext()) {
        OntProperty p = ont.next();
        if(p.isFunctionalProperty()) {
            p.removeProperty(RDF.type, OWL.FunctionalProperty);
        }
    }
```

But currently it yield java.util.ConcurrentModificationException error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The various ontology API classes in Jena, such as `FunctionalProperty` are there just to provide a convenient programming API. All of the state information is actually held in the underlying `Model`. Therefore, to make a property not be a functional property any more, you just need to remove the corresponding `rdf:type` triple from the model.

For example (untested code, but should work):

```java
OntModel m = ModelFactory.createOntology( OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM );
NS = "http://www.example.com/ontology#";
FunctionalProperty p = m.createFunctionalProperty( NS + "p" );

// now change p to normal object property
// setRDFType removes all existing rdf:type triples and adds one new one
// alternatively, we could just call:
//     p.removeProperty( RDF.type, OWL.FunctionalProperty );
p.setRDFType( OWL.ObjectProperty );
ObjectProperty p1 = p.as( ObjectProperty.class );
```

**Update**

Your code throws a `ConcurrentModificationError` because you are trying to make changes to a collection while iterating over that collection - hence *modifying* it *concurrently* with iterating. The solution is to do the work in two phases: first create a collection object, such as an `ArrayList` with the properties you want to change, and secondly make the changes to those properties.

```java
List<FunctionalProperty> fps = new ArrayList<FunctionalProperty>();
Iterator<OntProperty> ont = model.listOntProperties();
  while(ont.hasNext()) {
    OntProperty p = ont.next();
    if(p.isFunctionalProperty()) {
        fps.add( p.asFunctionalProperty() );
    }
}
for (FunctionalProperty fp: fps) {
  fp.removeProperty(RDF.type, OWL.FunctionalProperty);
}
```

Comment: Ian, I tried both of of your approach, but both yield same error: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException. I modified the question and add part of my code to give the context.

Comment: CME is a Java programming issue, not a Jena issue. But I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and explanation! Seems I still have a lot to learn in java itself..